# Hadoop: Outside of Eclipse List looses Data

Tags: java, eclipse, list, hadoop, mapreduce

I've written a simple MapReduce job (based on the Word Count example) to get the total count of words in a text file. I go through the file line by line and before mapping it I do some processing. All of that seems to work except deleting certain words from the line before mapping it.

Before starting the job I read in a list of words from a file that should be deleted before mapping a line. I let the program print out the list of words after reading it in and it works fine.
The problem is: As soon as the job starts my ArrayList containing the words seems to be empty again. Funny thing is, it only happens when starting the program outside of eclipse (jar-file), in eclipse the words get deleted.
The final result outside of eclipse is 13.2 million although it should be 13.4 million words in total (without deleting the words from the list). Within eclipse the result is 8.4 million as it should be.

Why is that? Thank you so much for your help!

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; 

import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.file.tfile.TFile.Reader.Scanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*; 

public class WordCount { 

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text,  NullWritable, IntWritable> { 

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1); 
        private final static NullWritable nullKey = NullWritable.get();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector< NullWritable, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException { 

            String processedline = LineProcessor.processLine(value.toString());

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(processedline); 
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { 
                tokenizer.nextToken();
                output.collect(nullKey, one); 
            } 
        }  

    } 

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<NullWritable, IntWritable, NullWritable, IntWritable> { 

        private final static NullWritable nullKey = NullWritable.get();

        public void reduce(NullWritable key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<NullWritable, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException { 

            int sum = 0; 
            while (values.hasNext()) { 
                sum += values.next().get(); 
            } 
            output.collect(nullKey, new IntWritable(sum)); 
        }

    } 

    public static class LineProcessor{
        public static ArrayList<String> stopWordsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public static void initializeStopWords() throws IOException{
            Path stop_words = new Path("/user/ds2013/stop_words/english_stop_list.txt");
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(stop_words)));
            String stopWord;
            stopWord = br.readLine();

            while (stopWord != null){
                //addToStopWords
                stopWordsList.add(stopWord);
                stopWord = br.readLine();
            }
        }

        public static String processLine(String line) {
            line = line.toLowerCase();
            //delete some punctuation
            char[] remove = {'.', ',','"'};
            for (char c : remove) {
                line = line.replace(""+c, "");
            }
            //Replace "-" with Space
            line = line.replace("-", " ");

            //delete stop Words
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line); 
            String nextWord = tokenizer.nextToken();
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {     
                if(stopWordsList.contains(nextWord)){
                    line = line.replace(nextWord, "");
                }
                nextWord = tokenizer.nextToken();
            } 

            return line;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class); 
        conf.setJobName("wordcount"); 
        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class); 
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class); 
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class); 

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class); 
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        //initialize List of words that should be deletet
        LineProcessor.initializeStopWords();

        //Directories

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("/user/ds2013/data/plot_summaries.txt"));


        Path outputDir = new Path( args[0] );
        //delete output folder if it already exists
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        fs.delete(outputDir, true);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, outputDir);


        JobClient.runJob(conf); 

    } 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of eclipse", do your start it in a real cluster?

Comment: By that I meant that I export it as a jar and start it using a command like this "hadoop jar wordCount.jar packageName.WordCount /data/wordcount"  It's all local in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you submit your job via the commandline it will create a client-side process for that. So the init you make in your main method:

```
LineProcessor.initializeStopWords();
```

is running in a completely different process. You normally move this init stuff into a setup function in your mapper that you can override (in the old API that you are using it is):

```
public void configure(JobConf job) {
   LineProcessor.initializeStopWords();
}
```

Or in the newer API it is:

```
public void setup(Context context) {
   LineProcessor.initializeStopWords();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to make sense. I'll try this as soon as I get home. So if I add a configure function to the mapper class, everything I do within that function (even if the ArrayList is outside of the mapper class) will work as expected because it's in the same process? And this configure function will always run before the actual map function (and only once per job so it doesn't initialize the list 13 million times)?

Comment: Yes, it will be run once for every mapper process (task in hadoop language) and right before the map calls.

Comment: Ok, I just got home, tried it and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much :-)